# Getting double of desired output

Tags: python, string

There is a binary string. We have to count number of substrings starting and ending with '1'.
I have gone with this approach but not getting desired output 
Please tell me where does code fails.

Code-:

```
st="1001101"
c=0
for i in st:
    if i=='1':
        for j in st[st.index(i)+1:]:
            if j=='1':
                c+=1

print(c)
```

Comment: You should tell us what output you are getting, and what your desired output is. If the code doesn't run, give us the stack traceback so we can see which line fails.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `st.index(i)` because as you have multiple `1` it always take the first

You may use `enumerate` to get both index and letter, for start letter

```
value = "1001101"
counter = 0
for idx, iletter in enumerate(value):
    if iletter == '1':
        for jletter in value[idx + 1:]:
            if jletter == '1':
                counter += 1
print(counter) # 6
```

Using a list comprehension, you can also compute the pairs of indexes that matches the requirement, then just take the length

```
pairs = [(i, j) for i in range(len(value)) 
                for j in range(i + 1, len(value)) 
                if value[i] == value[j] == "1"]

# [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 6), (3, 4), (3, 6), (4, 6)]
print(len(pairs)) #6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a math question...to know the answer, you only need to count number of 1's (call this c1), then the answer is nCr(n=c1, r=2)

```
st="1001101"
c1=0
for i in st:
    if i=='1': c1+=1

c=c1*(c1-1)//2

print(c)
```

BTW, the code in question fails because `st.index(i)` is always 1. You find the first occurrence of i='1' from st, but st starts with a '1' (or logically the first '1' from string). To correct it:

```
st="1001101"
c=0
st_len=len(st)
for i in range(0, st_len):
    if st[i]=='1':
        for j in range(i+1, st_len):
            if st[j]=='1':
                c+=1

print(c)
```